# Unable to copy dll when two instances of Visual Studio accessing

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Getting the following error message when running two instances of Visual Studio 2008 accessing the same common library 'xyz'.

How can this be solved?

> Unable to copy file obj\debug\xyz.dll to bin\debug\xyz.dll. The process cannot access the file bin\debug\xyz.dll because it is being used by another process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggest that both projects should reference the assembly in a directory other than `bin`. Suggest you create a `lib` folder outside both solutions where both can reference this assembly.

The root of your problem is that Instance1 wants to build and overwrite the .dll in `bin`, but can't, since Instance2 is locking it.

Using the suggested method above, your reference would be to a static location that isn't under change.

Comment: Appreciate you responding. I have added the reference to library as project reference instead of directly referencing the library dll.

Comment: @Chili: good stuff. Feel free to mark the answer as 'accepted answer' with the green checkmark if you feel is the right/best answer.